# Bootstrap - Header does not dropdown

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/nav.css"> <!—secondary bootstrap code—!>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.css">   
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>  </head>
<body>
 
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/link">Link</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Paid Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Flash Documentation</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">SMS Bomb</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">MDickie Projects</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">BxPP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello community of Stackoverflow. This bootstrap header doesn't dropdown on mobile devices. I have the JS and CSS, and I really don't know what do. Can someone help? Replace the "/" with atproducts.xyz since it triggered the spam filter.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your local css. I've replace this rows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/nav.css"> <!—secondary bootstrap code—!>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.css">
```

With the official bootstrap CDN and it works.

So your page should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
      </head>
<body>
 
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/link">Link</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Paid Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Flash Documentation</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">SMS Bomb</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">MDickie Projects</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">BxPP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/link">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </header>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've also moved the script at the bottom, before the body closing .

Comment: I'd still like to use my custom bootstrap, because it is more mobile friendly and supports some other CSS element that breaks with the official CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `<head>` tag and it will work. Also do not download the single file of bootstrap instead [download the whole bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v5.2.2/bootstrap-5.2.2-dist.zip) and then include it in your project.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  ...
</head>
```

Also move the bootstrap JS link to the end of your `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
  ...
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: If you find it working for you kindly mark the answer as accepted.